# why does Laravel-echo-server try to connect to the wrong server?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo

I tried setting up a laravel-echo-server with the init command, when I try to start it with `laravel-echo-server start` i get this output:

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.3.8

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
```

and so on. I don't really know why its trying to connect to 127.0.0.1, even though I stated in the config otherwise. Here is the laravel-echo-server.json:

```
{
    "authHost": "https://mydomain.test",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "myid",
            "key": "mykey"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "mydomain.test"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "https",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "/etc/ssl/crt.crt",
    "sslKeyPath": "/etc/ssl/key.key",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong here? I wasn't able to find anyone with a similar problem (maybe because its so obvious?) but i don't really get why it doesn't try to connect to https://mydomain.test:6379 and instead connects to 127.0.0.1

thanks in advance guys, if you need any more code, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're Laravel Echo installation is trying to connect to a Redis Server. You need to either install Redis and configure it or use one of the other Laravel Broadcasting Drivers

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#configuration)

Comment: I did `composer require predis/predis` as stated in the guide that i was following. Is that what you mean? the laravel doc doesn't say more about redis than that

Comment: Are you by any chance running inside a Homestead instance?

Comment: @Nais_One Ah, that's all the info I need: You need to download and install Redis [https://redis.io/](https://redis.io/) and then try again. Redis isn't a standard program.

Comment: Thank you! thats exactly what i was missing, i thought the guide would have told me something like that.

Comment: @Nais_One Just some clarification: You said in your question that Laravel Echo connected to the wrong server (127.0.0.1). I don't know if you know this, but 127.0.0.1 is an alias for your own computer (like localhost, or IPv6's ::1). So don't worry whenever you see that IP address ;)